Win 10 won't boot, sfc fails to run from external USB Win 10
HP AIO, 8th Gen CPU. Win 10, newest, startup repair runs, can't fix. Reset also fails. Restore point also fails.
Using a known-good USB ISO also fails to fix (windows resource protection could not perform the requested operation). Managed to run chkdsk, no drive issues. Can browse directories via cmd.
I'm going to backup the data first, probably with Linux Mint, then what do you reckon? I'm thinking registry, but no experience fixing that (if it's possible?).
Let me know if you need more info/what/how to extract & post.
Cheers

I would suggest to examine the SMART attributes of the disk, to be sure about its health. You may add this to your post if you wish us to examine it.

chkdsk came back as all good, as I said, so it's not the disk. None of the "fixes" actually do anything, as per usual-M$. Ran the HP diagnostics, also all good.
One thing I noticed, on restart my KB stops working & I have to unplug/replug it in. I'm wondering now if there's a bad USB driver that got installed. However, I can't get into safe mode. When I choose to change startup behaviour, I get the proper screen to press 4, but it ignores that and goes directly to startup repair, which fails! Is there a way to force safe mode from RE or a Win 10 USB? Maybe startup repair will work in SM?

Well, I spent time today attempting about a dozen ideas from Bootrec to DISM (online/offline). Nothing worked. I had the data backed up, so I've just reinstalled. I would've liked to figure it out, but it was not to be!

I’m voting to close this question because OP ended up reinstalling the OS entirely. Issue can no longer be reproduced.
